# Is my shared host skimping on memory? Should I switch hosts or try and decrease memory usage in my MVC app?

Tags: server, shared-hosting, asp.net-mvc

I am running a .NET MVC 4 site on a shared host and am getting frequent out of memory errors.  They are most common after updating the web.config file and / or logging in.

I suspect the host is skimping on memory and am considering moving to another host.

When I first contacted them about this they said:

> *"Your website is in dedicated application pool with 128 MB RAM limit. If the website hits the limit the pool recycles. If it recycles too
>   often for a short  period of time it stops in order to prevent from
>   server overload. The higher memory usage may be caused by traffic,
>   generated files, not killed objects, etc. Please, review the code and
>   try to decrease the memory usage"*

But I don't see how I can decrease memory usage.

The site is pretty standard MVC stuff and not memory intensive in any way that I'm aware of. For example I often get OOM errors when trying to login, however the site uses the MVC login that comes out of the box.

(It might be worth mentioning that it compiles LESS server side - and I'm not sure how memory intensive that is - but surely not enough to kill the app?!).

Comment: Perhaps it is time to move to a VPS.  Inevitably as a website grows, it also outgrows shared hosting.  Also, the cheaper per month shared hosting costs, the more customers!ers they are likely to jam onto a machine

Comment: It's just a bit annoying as they claim the hosting is suitable for MVC apps, when clearly it's not. I was just looking for budget hosting as the site is very simple and perhaps won't be inundated by visitors. :)